# How can I search for 'drupal_render' exactly, not ('drupal' or 'render')?

Tags: support, search

On *Drupal Answers*, I am trying to look for drupal_render, which is the name of a Drupal function. If I search for [drupal_render](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=drupal_render&submit=search), I get posts containing *Drupal*, *render*, or *drupal*. If I search for [code:"drupal_render"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=code:%22drupal_render%22&submit=search), I get only posts where drupal_render is contained in a code block.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to tell the search page to look only for drupal_render?
I tried with ["drupal_render"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22drupal_render%22&submit=search), and [`"drupal\_render"`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22drupal%5C_render%22&submit=search) (escaping the underscore), but the result doesn't change much from when I search for drupal_render.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect not, since chances are good that in normal text "drupal_render" is just indexed as the two separate tokens "drupal" and "render" (this is the default behaviour for Lucene, if I recall correctly). But I don't know enough about the actual implementation to be positive.

Comment: Well, you could always use google. Search for site:http://drupal.stackexchange.com "drupal_render"

Comment: It does seem to work fine now.

Comment: @nicael The underscore can now be used in a search and it will be not anymore treated as word separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore is not anymore used as word separator. I can now search for *drupal_render* and get posts containing exactly *drupal_render*, not *drupal* or *render*. Nothing particular is required, such as escaping the underscore.

> [image: screenshot]

What searched gets also correctly highlighted.